# Reduce the size of asp.net mvc web application using only the packages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do create asp.net mvc web application without any package type Owin, Twitter and the like? I created ASP.Net MVC web application and watch the project is too big = ~ 110-120 MB. It's too large file size. It is clear that the need to remove packages. What to do?

Comment: The answer given below, to my question. He allowed my bewilderment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the MVC project, click the "Change Authentication" button and select "No Authentication".